What is a regular expression for the letter "i" all by itself?
In the following English sentences, the letter i is not capitalized correctly.
with this notice know that i inscribe messages to inform.
a boy named "Will" said into a microphone that time is like a high-five.
i give lines to computers to find cities and sites. 
i am my eyes, and to view is to exist (cuanda tu ve, tu comprendes el significado del 'hay')
view that i will not be processing your application any further because i am eating an apple.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wIth thIs notIce know that I InscrIbe messages to Inform.
a boy named "WIll" saId Into a mIcrophone that tIme Is lIke a hIgh-fIve.
I gIve lInes to computers to fInd cItIes and sItes. 
I am my eyes, and to vIew Is to exIst (cuanda tu ve, tu comprendes el sIgnIfIcado del 'hay')
vIew that I wIll not be processIng your applIcatIon any further because I am eatIng an apple.

What Python script will find the letter i when it is not inside of an another word?
The idea is to ignore the letter i when it occurs inside of a larger word. We wish to locate the letter only when it is isolated and/or used as a first-person singular pronoun.

\bi\b or \bI\b or simply (?i)\bi\b.

You can use a word boundary (\b) and re.sub() with \bi\b pattern:
import re

s = """with this notice know that i inscribe messages to inform.
a boy named "Will" said into a microphone that time is like a high-five.
i give lines to computers to find cities and sites. 
i am my eyes, and to view is to exist (cuanda tu ve, tu comprendes el significado del 'hay')
view that i will not be processing your application any further because i am eating an apple.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wIth thIs notIce know that I InscrIbe messages to Inform.
a boy named "WIll" saId Into a mIcrophone that tIme Is lIke a hIgh-fIve.
I gIve lInes to computers to fInd cItIes and sItes. 
I am my eyes, and to vIew Is to exIst (cuanda tu ve, tu comprendes el sIgnIfIcado del 'hay')
vIew that I wIll not be processIng your applIcatIon any further because I am eatIng an apple.
"""

print(re.sub(r'\bi\b', 'I', s))

Prints
with this notice know that I inscribe messages to inform.
a boy named "Will" said into a microphone that time is like a high-five.
I give lines to computers to find cities and sites. 
I am my eyes, and to view is to exist (cuanda tu ve, tu comprendes el significado del 'hay')
view that I will not be processing your application any further because I am eating an apple.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wIth thIs notIce know that I InscrIbe messages to Inform.
a boy named "WIll" saId Into a mIcrophone that tIme Is lIke a hIgh-fIve.
I gIve lInes to computers to fInd cItIes and sItes. 
I am my eyes, and to vIew Is to exIst (cuanda tu ve, tu comprendes el sIgnIfIcado del 'hay')
vIew that I wIll not be processIng your applIcatIon any further because I am eatIng an apple.


Of course one needs more test cases to check that this solution is (i) correct, (ii) error-free, (iii) universally applicable, and (iv) performant.

That’s pretty much universally applicable to any code

I guess @HagenvonEitzen was also attempting to demonstrate that (i) in their comment would also incorrectly be replaced.

@tripleee Exactly! I realized that. Thanks!
